# Open form based on int

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm just starting Project Euler and I have already ran into my first issue. I want to have a separate form for every Euler Problem but I cannot figure out how to open the forms in a good way. What I want to do is use the variable problemNumber to open a form. For example if I have problemNumber set to 54 and I press a button it should open form54.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
    {
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             int problemNumber = int.Parse(numericUpDown1.Text);


        }
    }
}
```

I do know how to open a specific form, for example form2.

```
form2 f2 = new form2();
f2.Show();
```

This would open up form2, but as mentioned above I want to open up form+problemNumber.

Thank you!

Comment: Tip: I found it to be really useful to use unit test to test the project Euler exercises. I implemented quite a few solutions to the exercises as utility functions to be reused in other exercises. The unit tests allowed me to tinker with them and make sure they still worked. Highly recommended.

Comment: how shall your ui look like? a dropdown or a listbox? just numbers or also titles & descriptions?

Answer (score 2):

One possibility would be to create a static class, that has one static method with a switch case and returns a `Form` object. In the method you create new form object regarding the specified number:

```
public static class FormStarter
{
    public static Form OpenForm(int formNumber)
    {
        Form form = null;
        switch (formNumber)
        {
            case 1: form = new Form1(); break;
            case 2: form = new Form2(); break;
            //case 3: form = new Form3(); break;
            // ...
            default: throw new ArgumentException();
        }

        return form;
    }
}
```

You can then use the class like this:

```
var f = FormStarter.OpenForm(2);
f.ShowDialog(); // Form2 is started!
```

Once you have a new form, you need to add the creation of the instance in only one method - the `OpenForm`.

Another possible solution without a static class would be a `Dictionary` object holding the number and the form instance like this:

```
Dictionary<int, Form> forms = new Dictionary<int, Form>();
forms.Add(1, new Form1());
forms.Add(2, new Form2());
forms[2].ShowDialog(); // Form2 is started!
```

If you want to reference just the type of the form in the dictionary and create an instance only when needed, then change the value of the dictionary to be of type `Type` and put the corresponding form in it:

```
Dictionary<int, Type> forms = new Dictionary<int, Type>();
forms.Add(1, typeof(Form1));
forms.Add(2, typeof(Form2));
((Form)Activator.CreateInstance(forms[2])).ShowDialog(); // Form2 is started!
```

Comment: I like that last option!

Answer (score 1):

I've made a small sample application to find a Form by name. The code to find the Form is

```
var types = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes();
var targetForm = types.FirstOrDefault(t => t.IsClass && t.Name == string.Format("Form{0}", formNumber);
if (targetForm != null)
{
    var form = (Form)Activator.CreateInstance(targetForm);
    form.ShowDialog();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a simple method which takes in the name of the form (you can change the namespace to the name of your project, I've just used the default `WindowsFormApplication1`). You can then name each form `Project{x}`.

```
public static Form GetForm(string id)
{
   return Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CreateInstance(String.Format("WindowsFormsApplication1.Project{0}", id)) as Form;
}
```

And use it like this

```
Form firstProjectForm = GetForm("1");
if(firstProjectForm != null)
   firstProjectForm.Show();
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be better ways to handle launching multiple forms than using the class name. However, here is some code that does what you asked, showing how you can call other methods than just Show. Change "yourNamespace."

```
using System.Reflection;

Type t = Type.GetType("yourNamespace.Form" + numericUpDown1.Text);
if (t!=null)
{
    object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
    MethodInfo mI = t.GetMethod("Show", new Type[0]);
    mI.Invoke(instance, null);
}
```

Comment: This is case-sensitive, so adjust it accordingly if you really named the class "form2" instead of "Form2" which I assumed.